How to take backup a specific schema with all its tables from Azure Datawarehouse (Dedicated SQL Pool)?
I am working an activity to delete all the unwanted schemas and tables form our Azure Datawarehouse service and i need to take backup of some schema's and their tables inside it.
However, when checking I see option to take backup of entire Database which is of 100+ TB.
Can anyone tell if its possible to take backup of specific schema and its table from azure data warehouse either in .bacpac or .bak format?

You've tagged Azure SQL Database and Azure Synapse here, but those are different products; which are you really using.

For the most part, however, SQL Server backups are an "all or nothing" thing.

@Thom, I am using Azure Data warehouse service.

In Azure Synapse, you cannot directly create a .bacpac file that includes only specific tables or schemas. The .bacpac format is designed to back up an entire database, not individual tables or schemas.
Know more about the Backup and restore dedicated SQL pools in Azure Synapse Analytics
Organize each database tables within their own dedicated database and reference them from a 'master' database using views within the tenant-specific schema.
For Example:
I have a database Db1.dbo.Table1
In the MasterDB, create the view create like below:
CREATE VIEW Db1.Table1
AS
SELECT * FROM Db1.dbo.Table1;

This approach allows for easy backup and restoration of individual databases. Some benefits include:
Individual databases can be restored without putting the main database into single-user mode.
Also  SQL Server abilities to backup and restore individual file groups.
